# How to save open3d visualizer to a 3D model (mesh or point cloud or others)?

Tags: python, 3d, point-clouds, open3d

I am using Open3D to visualize 3D point clouds of a changing pose. After some operations on my visualizer, I am unable to find a solution in order to save properly the 3D Model of my geometry visualized.

I first load a point cloud using open3d using  (see picture) :

```
open3d.io.read_point_cloud(filename, format='auto', remove_nan_points=False, remove_infinite_points=False, print_progress=False)
```

See : http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.io.read_point_cloud.html#open3d.io.read_point_cloud

[Initial point cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krkTy.png)

After having changed a point cloud to a geometry and added several other geometries to my visualizer, I obtain this (see screenshot below) :

[Visualization output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7eJN.png)

The closest thing to a 3D model I found on the documentation is

```
visualization.capture_depth_point_cloud(filename, do_render=False, convert_to_world_coordinate=False)
```

See : http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.visualization.Visualizer.html#open3d.visualization.Visualizer.capture_depth_point_cloud

However it seem to have lost a lot of the properties of the visualization (see screenshot below) :

[Saving visualization as pointcloud output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE59F.png)

How can I retrieve the 3D model of the visualization ?

I am using python==3.10.10, open3D==0.17.0 and for the preview of 3d model the VS code extension vscode-3d-preview

Comment: Hi there, did you find any solution to this problem ? as i am also facing the same issue